# .htaccess - how to remove repeated words in url?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the **regex** in `.htaccess` to go from those urls:

```
example.com/hello-world-world
example.com/hello-world-hello
```

to this one:

```
example.com/hello-world
```

using RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^REGEX$
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So what have you tried ? Also how in the world is such url's possible ? If the client types in the wrong url (with repeated words) then it's his own fault and you should just show something like 404.

Comment: RafaSashi It might be possible but `/hello-world-hello` will become `/world-hello` is that fine?

Comment: I try to avoid duplicate words in slugs after escaping stopwords. For example: "Say hello to the world: hello!" would become "say-hello-world-hello" and I was wondering if an htaccess regular expression could do the job. What do you have anubhava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all the duplicate words from slug is **pretty tricky** to be done in `mod_rewrite` only but here is a `lookahead based` regex rule than you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/((?:[^-]*-)*)([^-]*)-((?=.*?\2).*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [L,R]
```

- This will redirect `/hello-world-world` to `/hello-world`
- This will redirect `/hello-world-hello` to `/world-hello`

**UPDATE:** As per your comments:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/site/var1/var2)/((?:[^-]*-)*)([^-]*)-((?=.*?\3).*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2%4 [L,R]
```

This will redirect `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello-world-world` to `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello-world` this removing the duplicate.

**UPDATE 2:** As per your comments:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/site/var1/var2)/((?:[^/]*/)*)([^/]*)/((?=.*?\3).*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2%4 [L,R]
```

This will redirect `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello/world/world/boy/boy` to `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello/world/boy`

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, this the best answer I have ever read so far. Unfortunately I cannot implement it yet according to my url structure but the rule works as you describe on the RegExr software I use. Is it possible to return %1%2%3 leaving %2 blank?

Comment: Thanks so much. `%2` is actually duplicate word which is found to be duplicate by lookahead `(?=.*?\2)` That's the reason I used `/%1%3` in the target URL to *take out* duplicate word from resulting URI.

Comment: All right. Now I cannot implement on `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello-world-hello` using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/((?:[^-]*-)*)([^-]*)-((?=.*?\2).*)$
RewriteRule . $1/$2$4 [R=301,L]` redirected to `http://localhost/C:/root/site`

Comment: I can now strike the rule escaping the slash like this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/((?:[^-]*-)*)([^-]*)-((?=.*?\2).*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2%4 [R=301,L]` but I am redirected to `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/world` Apache doesn't react like the RegExr software...

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in mod_rewrite. I can suggest you this rule. So you want `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/hello-world-hello` to become `http://localhost/site/var1/var2/world-hello` right?

Comment: I see. I am more interested in the first case `/hello-world-world` becoming `/hello-world` but the second case like `/world-hello` would also be great. For now if I use your first suggestion the last word of the slug shows up regardless of the slug structure

Comment: It works perfectly! I wish could triple vote you up for this. Last request and I am done. Could you make a variant for repeated directories such as `/var1/var2/hello/world/world` for example. I don't see how to deal with the starting slash.

Comment: Yes I can provide you that, give me some time as I am about to leave for home, I will provide you that answer in my evening.

Comment: This regex will see `a` and then any word that starts with `a` as a duplicate.

Comment: @RafaSashi: See update2 for variant for repeated directories solution.

Comment: Thanks! As you said the variant is pretty tricky to implement with other rules but it is theoretically working. In this case I was looking for merging `var2` in `/var1/var2/var2/hello-world` but apache keep `var2/var2` as two distinct variables

Comment: When I changed rule condition to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/site)/((?:[^/]*/)*)([^/]*)/((?=.*?\3).*)$ [NC]` and opened `/site/var1/var2/var2/hello-world` it became `/site/var1/var2/hello-world`

Answer (score 1):

According to your very good answer Anubhava here is my **solution to rewrite the slug** at the end of any url and not only based on `/site/var1/var2`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/((?:[^-]*-)*)([^-]*)-((?=.*?\3).*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2%4 [R=301,L]
```