# .htaccess - how to compare names in url based on lookahead regex rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given the following url structure: `http://localhost/name/name`

And the following env variables:

```
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=ORIG_REQUEST:name/name]
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=DIR_NAME:name]
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=FILE_NAME:name]
```

How to check if `DIR_NAME` is equal to `FILE_NAME` based on a `lookahead` regex rule ?

what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{ENV:ORIG_REQUEST} ^([^/]+)/(?=\1)$ [NC]
RewriteRule - [E=IS_EQUAL:true]
```

Inspired by [.htaccess - how to remove repeated words in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433966/htaccess-how-to-remove-repeated-words-in-url)

Comment: Can I ask you what you are trying to accomplish? Meaning what is not working and I don't mean your rules. It seem using on the environment vars is overcomplicating things.

Comment: I am just trying to match `name/name` with a lookahead regex rule in htaccess and I am asking because I am new with lookahead regex and I don't get it. I dont think the problem has anything to do with environment vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if `DIR_NAME` is equal to `FILE_NAME` based on a lookahead regex rule?

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ORIG_REQUEST:name/name]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DIR_NAME:name]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=FILE_NAME:name]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DIR_NAME}#%{ENV:FILE_NAME} ^([^#]+)#\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_EQUAL:true]
```

- `#` is just used as a separator between 2 variables. It can be anything.
- `([^#]+)` captures first variable `DIR_NAME` in matched group #1
- `\1` is back-reference of captured value from first string

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. It will not match if dir is not equal to file

```
   :\/\/\w+\/(\w+)\/(?=\1)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/kC9mM0/1).

Comment: Thanks! could you provide an htaccess regex to match only `dir1/dir1`. `%{ENV:ORIG_REQUEST} ^(\w+)/(?=\1)$ [NC]` not working

Comment: @RafaSashi, consultez la réponse de anubhava ! J'ai répondu à ta question avant ta dernière édition.

Comment: @RafaSashi je crois que SO est un outil pour aider les gens tout simplement et ça arrête la-bas. Je ne l'ai jamais vu comme une compétition pour gagner des points de réputation *virtuels*. C'est au sens de communauté que j'en crois plus! Je ne pense pas qu'on est validé comme ingénieur ou programmeur avec des points SO! Que penses-tu?